# Procedure para armazenar em tabelas backup?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho duas tabelas, vendas e vendaProduto por conta do volume de informações nessas tabelas as operações de leitura/escrita ficam lentas. Preciso criar uma procedure que armazene esses dados (das tabelas venda e vendaProduto), de um determinado período, em tabelas de backup (bkpVenda e bkpVendaProduto). Sendo que o período irá ser informado pelo usuário. Como eu devo fazer essa procedure?

```
create table venda (
ven_ID   int not null identity (1,1) constraint PKVenda primary key,
cli_ID   int not null,
fun_ID   int not null, 
ven_Data date not null,
constraint fkVenCli foreign key (cli_ID) references cliente(cli_ID),
constraint fkVenFun foreign key (fun_ID) references funcionario(fun_ID))
```

;

```
create table vendaProduto (
vpr_ID          int identity (1,1) constraint PKVendaProduto primary key,
ven_ID          int not null,
liv_ID          int not null, 
vpr_Quantidade  int,
vpr_ValorUnit   decimal(15,2),
constraint fkItvVen foreign key (ven_ID) references venda(ven_ID),
constraint fkItvliv foreign key (liv_ID) references livro(liv_ID))
```

;

Comment: Felipe, os dados que forem copiados para as respectivas tabelas de backup devem ser apagados da tabela original? Se sim, terá que reprogramar o aplicativo para consultar tanto os dados ativos quanto os arquivados.

Comment: Felipe, qual o número aproximado de linhas nas tabelas "venda" e "vendaProduto"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
if object_id('realizar_backup', 'P') is null
begin
  exec('create procedure realizar_backup as');
end;
go

alter procedure realizar_backup @data_inicio datetime,
                                @data_fim    datetime
as
begin
  set nocount on;

  insert into bkpVenda(ven_ID,
                       cli_ID,
                       fun_ID, 
                       ven_Data)
  select v.ven_ID,
         v.cli_ID,
         v.fun_ID, 
         v.ven_Data
    from venda with(readpast) v
   where v.ven_Data between data_inicio and data_fim;

  insert into bkpVendaProduto(vpr_ID,
                              ven_ID,
                              liv_ID 
                              vpr_Quantidade,
                              vpr_ValorUnit)
  select vp.vpr_ID,
         vp.ven_ID,
         vp.liv_ID 
         vp.vpr_Quantidade,
         vp.vpr_ValorUnit
    from venda with(readpast) v
         inner join vendaProduto with(readpast) vp on vp.ven_ID = v.ven_ID
   where v.ven_Data between data_inicio and data_fim;
end;
go
```

**Porém** eu te aconselho a gravar em tabelas de `log` no momento em que as transações são feitas (`insert`, `update`, `delete`) e depois só consultar por datas. Mas se for só pra salvar essa `procedure` resolve seu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de modificar a estrutura do banco de dados, e o respectivo impacto nos  aplicativos, sugiro análise do que está ocasionando a lentidão. Podem ser estatísticas defasadas, alguma consulta que necessita ser otimizada, índices fragmentados ou ausentes etc etc. Em suma, as tarefas típicas de administração de banco de dados.

Após a análise, talvez seja indicada a criação de índices adicionais. Por exemplo, se houver elevado número de consultas na tabela "venda" por período, então é provável que a criação de índice pela coluna ven_Data otimize essas consultas. É claro que, além da coluna ven_Data, é necessário avaliar colunas de cobertura que devam constar nesse índice.

Na tabela vendaProduto me parece que deve ser reavaliado o que comporá o índice *clustered*. A coluna vpr_ID, como chave do índice *clustered*, me parece inútil. Ela até poderia ser mantida como chave primária, mas em um índice *nonclustered*. Ou, melhor ainda, bastaria declarar essa coluna como *unique*.

Dentre as várias chaves candidatas da tabela "vendaProduto", talvez a coluna ven_ID seja a ideal para ser escolhida como chave do índice *clustered*. Pode ser uma chave simples, aceitando duplicidades, ou então uma chave composta (ven_ID + vpr_ID), exclusiva (sem repetições).

A sugestão é que, antes de pensar em modificar a estrutura do banco de dados, encontre os gargalos atuais.

Com relação ao espaço físico ocupado, analise quanto ocupa cada coluna. Somente como exemplo, a coluna Quantidade da tabela "vendaProduto" está declarada como *int*. Ou seja, ocupa 4 bytes e aceita valores de até 2 milhões e pouco. Será que algum livro teve mais de 32 mil exemplares vendidos, em uma mesma transação? Se  a quantidade de cada item vendido for menor do que 32 mil unidades, pode declarar a coluna como *smallint*, que então a coluna ocupará metade do espaço (2 bytes).

O mesmo raciocício para a coluna fun_ID, na tabela "venda", que também está declarada como *int*. Existem mais de 32 mil funcionários nessa livraria?! Claro que não! Essa coluna poderia ser declarada como *smallint* (até cerca de 32 mil funcionários) ou mesmo *tinyint* (até 255 funcionários).

Na tabela "venda" consta a data da venda mas não consta o horário. Se for necessário registrar também o horário da venda, avalie o uso do tipo *smalldatetime*. O tipo *date* ocupa 3 bytes e o smalldatetime ocupa 4 bytes.

São detalhes que, ao final, fazem a diferença na performance.